# How to obtain attributes within div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

i'm trying to obtain the attributes within the div tag, but I don't know how to get the first child's attributes within a div.

I'm webscraping and using node, with puppeteer. I'm trying to obtain the first child's custom attributes, data ticker, data-sentiment, and the rest of everything in there. In the HTML sample, I want:

`data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG"`

I want to put "SPY, bearish, 777, 123, BIG" into an array of sorts.

A modified sample HTML of the website is below, inside the childs are more divs, but those I don't want:

```
<div class="data-body">
   <div class="item bearflow " data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG">
   <div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="MSFT" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="222" data-premiumpaid="321" data-ordertype="SMALL">
   <div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="AMD" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="555" data-premiumpaid="132" data-ordertype="BIG">
   // more divs of the same format follow
>/div>
```

Here's what i've tried:

`let flow = document.querySelector('#optionflow > div.data-body > div:nth-child(1)').innerText;`
This goes into the first child's elements, and gives me it's text, not helpful for me.

`let flow = document.querySelector('#optionflow > div.data-body')[0];` I'm not even sure if this makes sense at all!

I'm a beginner at JavaScript and I looked through HTML DOM methods but I didn't get or understand anything useful. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `.querySelector()` doesn't return a list, hence the `[0]` doesn't make much sense as it will always return `undefined`. Have a look at the [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property

Comment: You dont have to use `:nth-child` because `querySelector` only selects the first matching element. If you want all elements and filter out a specific element use `querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let flow = document.querySelector('div.data-body > div:nth-child(1)').attributes;
let modified = Array.from(flow).map(attribute => ({
    name: attribute.localName,
  value: attribute.nodeValue
}));
console.log(modified);
```

```html
<div class="data-body">
<div class="item bearflow " data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG">aaa</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="MSFT" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="222" data-premiumpaid="321" data-ordertype="SMALL">bbb</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="AMD" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="555" data-premiumpaid="132" data-ordertype="BIG">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Try code like that. The 'attributes' array isn't exactly an array, and it has lots of information you won't want, hence the `Arra.from().map()` to turn it into something generally usable.

[edit] instead of `localName` and `nodeValue`, you can just use `name` and `value`, as per [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry for not making my question clearer, I still need help, thank you! I'm trying to obtain the first child's custom attributes, data ticker, data-sentiment, and the rest of everything in there.

I want to put "SPY, bearish, 777, 123, BIG" into an array of sorts.

Comment: @BaileyNguyen ok, so surely you can use the code I gave to accomplish that now.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` supports all valid CSS selectors, so selecting elements simply by its attributes is much easier than filtering it out using `:nth-child()`

So if you want to select this element:

```
data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG"
```

Then use:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('[data-ticker="SPY"]');

console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="data-body">
<div class="item bearflow " data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG">aaa</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="MSFT" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="222" data-premiumpaid="321" data-ordertype="SMALL">bbb</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="AMD" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="555" data-premiumpaid="132" data-ordertype="BIG">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Or if you always want the first `.item` in `.data-body` use

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.data-body .item');

console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="data-body">
<div class="item bearflow " data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG">aaa</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="MSFT" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="222" data-premiumpaid="321" data-ordertype="SMALL">bbb</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="AMD" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="555" data-premiumpaid="132" data-ordertype="BIG">ccc</div>
</div>
```

You can list the custom `data-*` attributes using `element.dataset`

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.data-body .item');

console.log(element.dataset);
```

```html
<div class="data-body">
<div class="item bearflow " data-ticker="SPY" data-sentiment="bearish" data-flowid="777" data-premiumpaid="123" data-ordertype="BIG">aaa</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="MSFT" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="222" data-premiumpaid="321" data-ordertype="SMALL">bbb</div>
<div class="item bullflow " data-ticker="AMD" data-sentiment="bullish" data-flowid="555" data-premiumpaid="132" data-ordertype="BIG">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are `::after`, `:visited` or `:active` invalid css selectors?

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry for not making my question more clearer. I want the custom attributes of the first child div. So for the sample HTML, I would want "SPY, bearish, 777, 123, BIG" into an array of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for:

```js
var sortArray = [];

$('.data-body').children().each(function() {;
  let attributes = $(this)[0].attributes;
  let str = "";
  let first = true;
  $(attributes).each(function(index) {
    if (index) {
      if (!first) {
        str += " ,";
      } else {
        first = false;
      }
      str += $(this)[0].value;
    }
  });
  sortArray.push(str);
});

console.log(sortArray);
```